# Pre-fill Form using URL Parameters

Tags: cognito-forms, javascript

I have been working on pre-filling a Cognito Form based on a customers answer to a different form on our website. I have gotten to the point where the JS variables contain the strings I would like to pre-fill into different fields, but I have tried everything from putting it into the Cognito.load() function, through inserting it as the value for an input field with .value() on a element ID.

I currently have two fields that pre-fill and work just fine by inserting JS variables through Cognito.load(), but the other fields will not.

```
    <div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/0XJ-E4DafE--nZOqqp-Haw"></script>
        <style>
          [data-field="Source"], [data-field="Query"] {display:none;}
        </style>
        <script>
          var url = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;

          var query = window.location.search;
          function getAllUrlParams(link) {


  var queryString = link ? link.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);


  var obj = {};


  if (queryString) {


    queryString = queryString.split('#')[0];


    var arr = queryString.split('&');

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

      var a = arr[i].split('=');


      var paramNum = undefined;
      var paramName = a[0].replace(/\[\d*\]/, function(v) {
        paramNum = v.slice(1,-1);
        return '';
      });


      var paramValue = typeof(a[1])==='undefined' ? true : a[1];


      if (obj[paramName]) {

        if (typeof obj[paramName] === 'string') {
          obj[paramName] = [obj[paramName]];
        }

        if (typeof paramNum === 'undefined') {

          obj[paramName].push(paramValue);
        }

        else {

          obj[paramName][paramNum] = paramValue;
        }
      }

      else {
        obj[paramName] = paramValue;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
          var nameFirst = decodeURIComponent(getAllUrlParams().nf);
          var nameLast = decodeURIComponent(getAllUrlParams().nl);
          var userEmail = decodeURIComponent(getAllUrlParams().e);
          var userPhone = decodeURIComponent(getAllUrlParams().p);
          Cognito.load("forms", { id: "44", entry: { "Source": url, "Query" : query, "Name": {"First": nameFirst, "Last": nameLast}, "Phone": userPhone, "PrimaryEmailAddress": userEmail}
});
```

As I mentioned above, the variables nameFirst, nameLast, userEmail, and userPhone all contain the proper information in them in my console. Insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm an engineer on the Cognito Forms team!</sup>

I created a mock form and was unable to replicate the problem, however, a few things you might want to note:

- If you make your `Source` and `Query` field's visibility *Internal*, you can still pre-populate it, and it will not be visible to your end users
- If your contact information fields (`Name`, `Phone`, and `PrimaryEmailAddress`) are within a section, you must specify the section name in the pre-fill.  One way to determine the underlying structure of the form is to set up a test JSON webhook (as outlined in [this article](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks)), create a sample entry, and take a look at the JSON output that is captured by requestb.in.

If you would like specific assistance with your form, please contact us via the *Support* option in the top-level menu.

Comment: Hi Bobby, 

I have tried everything from using the section name (BasicInformation) to target as seen below (from the help article on your website), to targeting with just the field name:

`"BasicInformation": [{"Name": {"First": nameFirst, "Last": nameLast}}, "Phone": userPhone, "PrimaryEmailAddress": userEmail]`

Let me know if there's something wrong with the way that was formatted, but as I said before, the odd part is that the Source and Query fields DO autofill, but the others don't. Thanks!